# uploading cordova base build to the appstore usning xcode 7 with Error itms-90032 no image found under key 'CFBundleIconFile': 'icon.png'

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, xcode7

[image]

When I upload a new build of my appache cordova's base application to the iTunesConnect via Xcode 7 I am getting this error message:

> Error itms-90032:"invalid image path- no image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFile': 'icon.png'"

I put all icons by selecting (use asset catalog) into Images.xcassets but when I submit my application to the app-store I get the above error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to remove the icon file reference in the .plist file

In xcode go to the project navigator -> Resources -> {projectname}-info.plist
Select Icon file and press - to remove it.

Comment: The same issue here. I'm using cordova 5.4.1. Mike, did you find the solution?

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved my issue! On Cordova 6.0.0, Xcode 7.2.1.

Comment: You just made my day. Thank you!

Comment: Live long and prosper